# Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

Currently i am running one MVC 5 project with web api where i am using angular js ajax call to fire web api method and get image path but when i am setting that path in img tag so image is not displaying and in chrome console message displays that not able to load local resource.

Below is the web api method code which i am calling through ajax

```html
[Route("Files")]
        public List<FilesInfo> GetImages()
        {
rootPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Images/");
            List<FilesInfo> files = new List<FilesInfo>();
 
            foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(rootPath))
            {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(item);
                files.Add(new FilesInfo(){FileName=f.Name, FilePath=rootPath+f.Name});  
            }

            return files;
            
        }
```

Please let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` [returns the physical path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx) on the server.
When you are adding this path to the `src` attribute of your `img`, the browser complains it cannot local *local* resource.

You'd need to adjust the path to the image to be relative to your site: */img/img1.jpg*

Try:

```
[Route("Files")]
public List<FilesInfo> GetImages()
{
    rootPath = "/Content/Images/";
    List<FilesInfo> files = new List<FilesInfo>();

    foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~"+ rootPath);))
    {
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(item);
        files.Add(new FilesInfo() { FileName = f.Name, FilePath = rootPath + f.Name });
    }

    return files;

}
```

This way `System.IO.FileInfo` should have the local path, and your `FilesInfo` should have the relative url path, which you can use with angular to create your: `<img ng-src="{{vm.file.filePath}}" alt="{{vm.file.fileName}}" />`

Comment: Hi Bruno, Thanks for your reply. But i did not get much, can you explore more? currently my image is inside project > Content > images >image1.jpg. Thanks.

Comment: You `FilesInfo.FilePath` shouldn't include C:\some\path. It must include the path of the image served by the web server: (mysite.com)/Content/image1.jpg Essentially you should be able to add this URL to the browser's navigation bar and see the image.

Comment: I have changed here but still getting issue. foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(rootPath))
            {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(item);
                files.Add(new FilesInfo(){FileName=f.Name, FilePath=f.DirectoryName+f.Name});  
            }

Comment: what's the value of FilePath?

Comment: The file path value is : D:\Vikash\Kentico\KenticoExamples\Insta\Insta\Content\Images\image1.jpg.

Comment: `rootPath + f.Name` should be creating: /Content/Images/image1.jpg Did you try the snippet I pasted?

Comment: Thanks Bruno I tried this code and it's work for me. I am upvoting your answer.